# Spring Boot DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to follow this guide
https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mysql/

but this guide is for the maven and i am trying the gradle

and getting this error

```
Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
```

in application.properties i have these things only.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_example
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

I tried all the possible things there is on the SO.

the only deps i have are these

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    runtimeOnly 'mysql:mysql-connector-java'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
}
```

Comment: `spring.datasource.url` is not set in your properties file. Assuming that you are using a local mysql database, probably it should be set to something like: `localhost:3306/mydb`

Comment: @Ervin I think it got missed due to the formatting of the stackoverflow. 
I have updated the question. 
Can you please let me know if there is something I am missing?

Comment: You can refer to this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52915923/failed-to-configure-a-datasource-url-attribute-is-not-specified-and-no-embedd

Comment: are you sure this application.properties file is used? where have you defined this properties file?

Comment: @Berthol I checked that question as well, they are telling me exclude the `DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class` which I don't want  to do.

Comment: @KumarV :: the `application.properties` is defined inside the under the `resource` folder.

Answer (score 1):

Or You will have to prevent Spring boot from automatically configuring the data source by adding this line to the file `application.properties`.

> `spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration`

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. Nope. This as well didn't worked. There was a question which mentioned such method. but unfortunately this didn't worked. But thank you!

Comment: I recommend this site to you. It will definitely help you. https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-failed-to-configure-data-source

Comment: Berthol :: Already tried those methods, still getting the following error. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of an old question but for anyone else coming across this, IF by any chance you are using IntelliJ (as OP does here based on his/her comments) make sure that our beloved IDE recognises your application.properties/application.yml as such by going to `File -> Project Structure -> Modules` then select your `resources` file and click on "Resources" from the `Mark as:` header thing (based on IntelliJ Community Edition 2019.1). Also keep in mind, as no doubt the IDE will certainly notify you, that by reimporting any Maven changes you will need to do this procedure again.

Answer (score 0):

Check the target classpath directory. If the application.properties file didn't exist, then delete the target and rebuild.

Comment: Where can I find this in intelliJ?

Answer (score 0):

I would search the reason somewhere else.

Your error log tells you  `Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class`. Please build your project, and check if mysql driver is included in a built jar file. If jar is missing try to change your mysql dependency scope from `runtimeOnly` to `implementation`.
The same problem can occur (at least I think so) if you try to run this project from IDE and solution should also help in that case.

`Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.` error is unfortunately very generic and can happen in many different situations. For example last week I had received this error while using oracle Oracle when there where special signs in password which was specified in `properties.yaml` without double-quotes.

Comment: I got the same error when I 'forgot' to include the H2 driver  in my build envronment

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and solved it by migrating my project that was in version `2.4.x`, to `2.3.x`.

Comment: Downgrading is never a solution

Answer (score 0):

in IDE / STS (spring tool suit), every thing was working fine
but when made a "project.jar" file,
this was thrown.

unnecessary spaces " " in the "application.yml" file can cause this.

```
server:
  port: 8085


spring:
 datasource:
  url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/studentdb
  username: root
  password: root
  driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
 jpa:
   hibernate:
    ddl-auto: update
   show-sql: true
   database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
 application:
  name: STUDENT-SERVICE
```

instead of tweaking my "application.yml" file
i simply moved all my statements in "application.yml" file to
"application.properties" file and formatted the statements like required in ".properties".

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/studentdb
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format.sql=true

spring.application.name=student-service

server.port=8085
```

**and voilà**

*(you can add params at the end of url)*
*(spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/studentdb?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false)*

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your pom.xml has the **war** packaging. It worked for me.

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

Answer (score -2):

Spring boot has chanegd the url to jdbc-url.

You need to use as below

spring.datasource.jdbc-url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_example

Document Link:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html#data-properties

Stressing that, of course, we would search the documentation for "spring.cloud.config.jdbc-url", but our search should be directly through spring.datasource.hikari.jdbc-url.

Comment: I am assuming you are using the Hikari connection Pool with spring boot. This is default. Check your pom dependency tree mvn dependency:tree to find out which jdbc pool jar you have. These attributes are realted to underline connection pool.